# embed youtube video with jwplayer on mobile device

Tags: youtube, jwplayer

when I try to play the video from this [link](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed) on a mobile device it's play with jwplayer, but when I've tried to implement the code suggested from the same link in my own website it's automatically play the video with youtube player.

how can I play the video with JWplayer on mobile ?? (android, ios)

the code:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjdLYBDUqw",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: [link](http://m.b144.co.il/mobile_v3/business_portal/FilmItem.aspx?code=11). if you try to emulate it on chrome it works fine, but on a mobile device it's openning with youtube player

Comment: Where is the JW Player on this page? It just re-directs me to your home page.

Comment: if you are using chrome you need to emulate the browser to mobile device (with developer tools) and then paste the link. http://m.b144.co.il/mobile_v3/business_portal/FilmItem.aspx?code=11

Comment: Can you just provide a test page that can easily be debugged? Do you have the same issue on this link? - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

Comment: I don't have the permission to upload a test page to the production. with the link you provided it seems to work fine on mobile (with jwplayer).

Comment: Is your site using the JW Player? Can you put a test page on dev?

Comment: --- http://m.b-soft.co.il/mobile_v3/business_portal/testJplayer.aspx --- if you'll open this link on a mobile device (I tested on LG G2) and play the video, it will use youtube player. if you want to debug this in chrome you need to emulate to mobile device. thanks

Comment: I want to view it on a desktop as well so I can debug the code. I can't debug on a phone. Please change the URL so it doesn't re-direct.